# Shortcut to insert code fragment in PhpStorm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I would like to make shortcut for inserting some code fragment, for example pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> should insert "$this->" in place where cursor is.

I know about Live Templates, but they are not shortcuts, it works like code complation, so i need to insert some text, and then i have to choose an template from context menu. Its cool for big code fragments, like foreach loop, but for very common and small code fragments, like '$this->' id like to have an shortcut.

Comment: PHPStorm is amazing, but it has sooo many options and choices and actions. Can you not just copy paste as PHPStorm keeps a record of all copy-memory held in the right click, paste-history selection. ?

Comment: You mean to copy that code, and then use shortcut for "paste from history", and then choose code to insert from context menu ?

Comment: Why context menu? -- keyboard only is enough. So ... `t[TAB]` as abbreviation for `$this->` (2 fast  keypresses) is too long to type/press?

Comment: In any case: your only option right now is to **record a macro** where you are typing/expanding such text and then assign any shortcut you want to your macro.

Comment: YEAH ! Macro is perfect :) Thanks. Shame you didn't post answer - would have earn some rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LazyOne suggested in comment, such things can be easily done with macros: start recording macro, type code, save macro, in keymap assign shortcut for created macro.